# TCS3200 color sensor not reading with delay lower then 4000 ms using TimerOne.h

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, library, timers

I'm trying to get the color sensor TCS3200 to give color values with a delay lower than 4000 ms. I've found a library to interface the TCS3200 from this [link](http://www.elecfreaks.com/5521.html).

I've modified the code to serve my needs and its works fine, almost! The before mentioned library uses [TimerOne.h](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Timer1), which can not accept a delay lower than 4000 ms.

My question is therefor, if it is somehow possible to modify my code, so I can lower the delay?

This is my code:

```c
#include <TimerOne.h>

#define S0     6
#define S1     5
#define S2     4
#define S3     3
#define OUT    2

int   g_count = 0;    // count the frequecy
int   g_array[3];     // store the RGB value
int   g_flag = 0;     // filter of RGB queue
float g_SF[3];        // save the RGB Scale factor

// Init TSC230 and setting Frequency.
void TSC_Init()
{
  pinMode(S0, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(S1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(S2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(S3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(OUT, INPUT);

  digitalWrite(S0, LOW);  // OUTPUT FREQUENCY SCALING 2%
  digitalWrite(S1, HIGH); 
}

// Select the filter color 
void TSC_FilterColor(int Level01, int Level02)
{
  if(Level01 != 0)
    Level01 = HIGH;

  if(Level02 != 0)
    Level02 = HIGH;

  digitalWrite(S2, Level01); 
  digitalWrite(S3, Level02); 
}

void TSC_Count()
{
  g_count ++ ;
}

void TSC_Callback()
{
  switch(g_flag)
  {
    case 0: 
         TSC_WB(LOW, LOW);              //Filter without Red
         break;
    case 1:
         g_array[0] = g_count;
         TSC_WB(HIGH, HIGH);            //Filter without Green
         break;
    case 2:
         g_array[1] = g_count;
         TSC_WB(LOW, HIGH);             //Filter without Blue
         break;
    case 3:
         g_array[2] = g_count;
         TSC_WB(HIGH, LOW);             //Clear(no filter)   
         break;
   default:
         g_count = 0;
         break;
  }
}

void TSC_WB(int Level0, int Level1)      //White Balance
{
  g_count = 0;
  g_flag ++;
  TSC_FilterColor(Level0, Level1);
  Timer1.setPeriod(1000000);             // set 1s period
}

void setup()
{
  TSC_Init();
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Timer1.initialize();             // defaulte is 1s
  Timer1.attachInterrupt(TSC_Callback);  
  attachInterrupt(0, TSC_Count, RISING);  

  delay(4000);

  for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
    Serial.println(g_array[i]);

  g_SF[0] = 255.0/ g_array[0];     //R Scale factor
  g_SF[1] = 255.0/ g_array[1] ;    //G Scale factor
  g_SF[2] = 255.0/ g_array[2] ;    //B Scale factor

  Serial.println(g_SF[0]);
  Serial.println(g_SF[1]);
  Serial.println(g_SF[2]);
}

void loop()
{
  g_flag = 0;

    int R = int(g_array[0] * g_SF[0]);
    int G = int(g_array[1] * g_SF[1]);
    int B = int(g_array[2] * g_SF[2]);    


    if((R>245) && (R<265) && (G>245) && (G<265) && (B>245) && (B<265))    // White
    {
      Serial.println("Color is white");
    }else if((R>24) && (R<44) && (G>56) && (G<76) && (B>95) && (B<115))  // Blue
    {
      Serial.println("Color is blue");
    }else if((R>56) && (R<76) && (G>107) && (G<127) && (B>80) && (B<100))  // Green
    {
      Serial.println("Color is green");    
    }else if((R>171) && (R<191) && (G>154) && (G<174) && (B>71) && (B<91))  // Yellow
    {
      Serial.println("Color is yellow");  
    }else if((R>77) && (R<97) && (G>46) && (G<66) && (B>43) && (B<63))  // Brown
    {
      Serial.println("Color is brown");    
    }else if((R>39) && (R<59) && (G>38) && (G<58) && (B>36) && (B<56))  // Brown dark
    {
      Serial.println("Color is brown dark");    
    }else if((R>20) && (R<40) && (G>43) && (G<63) && (B>48) && (B<68))  // Turkis
    {
       Serial.println("Color is turkis");   
    }else if((R>39) && (R<59) && (G>77) && (G<97) && (B>55) && (B<75))  // Green
    {
       Serial.println("Color is green");   
    }else
    {
      Serial.print("Red = ");
      Serial.println(R);
      Serial.print("Green = ");
      Serial.println(G);
      Serial.print("Blue = ");
      Serial.println(B);

    };

   delay(4000);
}
```

I've searched all over the net and didn't find any good solutions, where I can still specify the colours by hex degree.

All help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: You can increase the frequency (x10) by setting S0 HIGH and S1 LOW. Then you can change the timerone frequency from once a second to once every 100ms (`Timer1.setPeriod(100000);`). Then you can change your delay to `delay(400)`. PS I think you only need to wait for a bit over 3 timerone cycles, so `delay(350)` should also work.

Comment: Try looking at the [datasheet](http://www.dfrobot.com/image/data/SEN0101/TCS3200%20TCS3210.pdf). No need to understand everything in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can increase the frequency (x10) by setting S0 HIGH and S1 LOW. Then you can change the timerone frequency from once a second to once every 100ms (Timer1.setPeriod(100000);). Then you can change your delay to delay(400).

PS I think you only need to wait for a bit over 3 timerone cycles, so delay(350) should also work.